# How to create a path when copying in a dockerfile?

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, supervisord

I'm try to copy some file in my php/dockerfile:

```
COPY ./supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor                 #work
COPY ../../config/supervisor/* /etc/supervisor/conf.d   #doesn't work

WORKDIR /home/wwwroot/
```

What should the correct path look like? This is my structure:

```
|config -> supervisor -> *
|
|docker -> php -> Dockerfile
|              -> supervisord.conf
|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The  path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot
>   COPY ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build
>   is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker
>   daemon.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

dockerfile has the context of its own directory, and its unable to go above.
this issue has a few workarounds, for instance:

- run the `docker build .` command on the directory you want to be the context, with `-f path/to/Dockerfile`
- another one - if you are using docker-compose, you can pass it a different context, for example, if youre structure goes like:

> ```
> .
> ├── docker-compose.yml
> └── app
>    ├── Dockerfile
> ```

then in your docker-compose file you can give it:

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app/Dockerfile
```

in this case, the context of the dockerfile will be 1 directory above. but thats seems a bit hacky to me.  the correct approach is to put the dockerfile where the files you are trying to copy exists.